# Iterative quantile estimation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, iteration, estimation, quantile

I'm trying to implement an interative algorithm to estimate quantiles in data that is generated from a Monte-Carlo simulation. I want to make it iterative, because I have many iterations and variables so storing all data points and using Matlab's *quantile* function would take much of the memory that I actually need for the simulation.

I found some approaches based on the [Robbin-Monro process](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/1521-4036(200010)42:6%3C729::AID-BIMJ729%3E3.0.CO;2-W/full), given by

[image: Formula]

The implementation with a control sequence c<sub>t</sub> = c / t where c is constant is quite straight forward. In the cited paper, they show that c = 2 * sqrt(2 * pi) gives quite good results, at least for the median. But they also propose an adaptive approach based on an estimation of the histogram. Unfortunately, I haven't figured out how to implement this adaptation yet.

I tested the [implementation with a constant](http://wikisend.com/download/290430/IterativeQuantileEstimation.zip) c for three test samples with 10.000 data points. The value c = 2 * sqrt(2 * pi) did not work well for me, but c = 100 looks quite good for the test samples. However, this selction is not very robust and failed in the actual Monte-Carlo simulation giving results wide off the mark.

```
probabilities = [0.1, 0.4, 0.7];
controlFactor = 100;
quantile = zeros(size(probabilities));
indicator = zeros(size(probabilities));
for index = 1:length(data)
    control = controlFactor / index;
    indices = (data(index) >= quantile);
    indicator(indices) = probabilities(indices);
    indices = (data(index) < quantile);
    indicator(indices) = probabilities(indices) - 1;
    quantile = quantile + control * indicator;
end
```

Is there a more robust solution for iterative quantile estimation or does anyone have an implementation for an adaptive approach with small memory consumption?

Comment: Several potetial problems: `indices` is an array of `1` & `0`, not sure what `probabilities(indices)` should do. Additionally I would think that you want something like `quantile(index) = quantile(index-1) + control * indicator;`. Finally I think that you have not implemented `c/t` correctly I would think that `t` is time, unless the instances between you data points is 1sek.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In my opinion, the index _t_ just stands for the iteration counter, so there is no time involved. The variable `quantile` is a vector of the same size as probabilities, in this case 1x3, containing the iterative quantile estimations for `probabilities = [0.1, 0.4, 0.7]`. The last line in the for-loop updates these estimation. The indices/indicator construction is my implementation of the indicator function _I_ that selects when to use `probabilities` or `probabilities - 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some of the adaptive iterative approaches that I found in literature without great success (not sure, if I did it right), I came up with a solution that gives me good results for my test samples and also for the actual Monte-Carlo-Simulation.

I buffer a subset of simulation results, compute the sample quantiles and average over all subset sample quantiles in the end. This seems to work quite well and without tuning many parameters. The only parameter is the buffer size which is 100 in my case.

The results converge quite fast and increasing sample size does not improve the results dramatically. There seems to be a small but constant bias that presumably is the averaged error of the subset sample quantiles. And that is the downside of my solution. By choosing the buffer size, one fixes the achievable accuracy. Increasing the buffer size reduces this bias. In the end, it seems to be a memory and accuracy tradeoff.

```
% Generate data
rng('default');
data = sqrt(0.5) * randn(10000, 1) + 5 * rand(10000, 1) + 10;

% Set parameters
probabilities = 0.2;

% Compute reference sample quantiles
quantileEstimation1 = quantile(data, probabilities);

% Estimate quantiles with computing the mean over a number of subset
% sample quantiles
subsetSize = 100;
quantileSum = 0;
for index = 1:length(data) / subsetSize;

    quantileSum = quantileSum + quantile(data(((index - 1) * subsetSize + 1):(index * subsetSize)), probabilities);

end
quantileEstimation2 = quantileSum / (length(data) / subsetSize);

% Estimate quantiles with iterative computation
quantileEstimation3 = zeros(size(probabilities));
indicator = zeros(size(probabilities));
controlFactor = 2 * sqrt(2 * pi);
for index = 1:length(data)

    control = controlFactor / index;
    indices = (data(index) >= quantileEstimation3);
    indicator(indices) = probabilities(indices);
    indices = (data(index) < quantileEstimation3);
    indicator(indices) = probabilities(indices) - 1;
    quantileEstimation3 = quantileEstimation3 + control * indicator;

end

fprintf('Reference result: %f\nSubset result: %f\nIterative result: %f\n\n', quantileEstimation1, quantileEstimation2, quantileEstimation3);
```

Comment: I just found [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171784/estimation-of-quantile-given-quantiles-of-subset) over at Cross Validated. It seems to be related.

Comment: It makes sense that the the `quantileEstimation3` would converge quickly or saturate as the change factor `control` quickly drops of thus new changes are adapted ever slower.

Comment: Yes, but even the adaptations of the control factor that I found and tried did not improve the results for me.